ggsave doesn't export well ggarrange plot
I want to export a ggarrange object as a .jpg or .tiff with dpi=300, using "mm" units, with a width of 107 mm.
Unfortunately, when using ggsave, I struggle to the desired output, every sizes are different when using "mm" units.
Output desired (an output where dimensions are realistic)

Current output (sizes are not correct)

Maybe the text size is too large for the output.
Please find a reproducible example
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

##### Initiating data
tmpDf <- data.frame(values1=1:12,
                    values2=rev(101:112),
                    group=rep(c("I", "II", "III"), 4))

##### Initiating plot
tmpPlot <- 
  ggplot(data=tmpDf, aes(x=values1, y=values2, color=group)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("Title") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5),
        plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0),
                     plot.title.position="plot", 
                     plot.caption.position="plot")

##### Initiating a group of plots
tmpPlotsGrouped <- 
  ggarrange(
    tmpPlot,
    tmpPlot,
    tmpPlot,
    nrow=1, ncol=3, widths=c(1, 1, 1))

##### Export as a jpg
ggsave(file="myPath/plotName.jpg", plot=tmpPlotsGrouped,
       units="mm", width=107, height=50, dpi=300)


That's normal. You need to adjust symbol and text sizes so that they look good in the file. Btw., there is no reason to create a JPG. PNG is always preferable.

Thank you for the tip, I will try with different sizes. Unfortunately I don't have the choice between JPG and PNG but I agree it is simpler with PNG.

Here's a good blog post on adjusting dimensions / resolution / text size in ggplot2 outputs: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/

Save the image like this: n <-3; ggsave(file="plotName.jpg", plot=tmpPlotsGrouped, units="mm", width=107*n, height=50*n, dpi=300*n) and then resize the image: library(imager); img <- load.image("plotName.jpg"); new_img <- img |> imresize(1/n); imager::save.image(new_img, "plotName_new.jpg", quality = 1)

Many thanks for the link and the code proposition. I tried it and unfortunately it outputted the exact same image twice with a size of 321mm (107*3)

To match what you see on screen with the plot panel or zoom, set the dpi to the ppi of your monitor, and adjust the size accordingly.
I want an image that is 107x50mm at 300 dpi, which is
> c(107,50)/25.5*300
[1] 1258.8235  588.2353

in pixels
to get that to match what I see in my plot zoom (with window scaled to desired size), I need to use
ggsave(file="myPath/plotName.jpg", plot=tmpPlotsGrouped, scale=1,
       units="px", width=1259, height=588, dpi=105)


This is perfect, thank you!
